# Render a fulltext exposed search bar separate from the rest of the filters

Tags: views, search

I would like to render my exposed fulltext search bar in a separate location from the rest of my search filters. My other exposed search filters are things like display number, sort order, etc... I am also using facets.

My current problem is that I need to render the search bar in a whole separate region from the rest of my exposed filters. My current solution is to render `{{ exposed }}` twice but then use CSS to `display: none` the items I don't want. This is just awfully hacky and is bad practice. Is there a way to split these forms into two separate exposed filters?

Answer (score 1):

You can render one by one by:

```
{{ exposed.filter_1}}
{{ exposed.filter_2}}
```

And group them as your wish.

About the render `{{ exposed }}` twice as your current solution, The items you don't want can be removed at the .twig, not CSS such:

```
{{ exposed|without('filter_1', 'filter_2') }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! This has gotten me closer for sure. I am currently rendering my filters like this which visually achieves what I am looking for: 
{{ exposed|without('filter_1') }}
{{ exposed|without('filter_2') }}

The main problem though, because "exposed" is a render array containing a form. The two forms (with identical ids) are conflicting with each other. As an example, if I change the display setting, then the textfield resets its value, and if I change the textfield, then the other fitlers are reset to their defaults as well. 

Ajax is getting confused as well.

Comment: You should take a look at `core\modules\views_ui\templates\views-ui-expose-filter-form.html.twig`. It display same filter form with separated parts by using {{ xxx|without('yyy') }} way. Besides, you can mix both (render one by one + render using |without) as my comment. Search `form|without` in Drupal core can give you some suggestions.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are referring to! So this works in the filter form; however, the exposed variable is actually in the views-view.html template. I was actually able to utilize this rendering of separate elements in the form template as you have described because I lucked out and it worked with my layout. It does require me to inject a custom slider view inside of the exposed filter form to make it look like my design. BUT IT WORKS! For other cases, I may not get so lucky if the exposed filters need to be rendered in completely different regions.